# Application is halting when using MethodInvoker in custom timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer-jobs, invocation

**Background:**

I need a high resolution timer for an embedded system solution, so I decide to use [MicroTimer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98346/Microsecond-and-Millisecond-NET-Timer) from [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project)...

BTW, I've developed a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application to test its efficiency in such applications and for avoiding *"cross-thread operation..."*, I have to use invocation methods, BackgroundWorker, etc. and decide to use this code:

```
private void btnMicorTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate new MicroTimer
    MicroLibrary.MicroTimer microTimer = new MicroLibrary.MicroTimer();
    // Add event handler
    microTimer.MicroTimerElapsed +=
        new MicroLibrary.MicroTimer.MicroTimerElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Call micro timer every 1000µs (1ms)
    microTimer.Interval = 1000;

    // Can choose to ignore event if late by Xµs (by default will try to catch up)
    // microTimer.IgnoreEventIfLateBy = 500;

    microTimer.Enabled = true; // Start timer

    // Do something whilst events are happening. For demo sleep, 2000 ms (2 sec).
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

    microTimer.Enabled = false; // Stop timer
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender,
                          MicroLibrary.MicroTimerEventArgs timerEventArgs)
{
    string response = string.Format(
                    "Count = {0:#,0}  Timer = {1:#,0} µs | " +
                    "LateBy = {2:#,0} µs | ExecutionTime = {3:#,0} µs",
                    timerEventArgs.TimerCount, timerEventArgs.ElapsedMicroseconds,
                    timerEventArgs.TimerLateBy, timerEventArgs.CallbackFunctionExecutionTime);

    // Do something small that takes significantly less time than Interval
    if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
            delegate
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(response);
            }));
    }
    else
        listBox1.Items.Add(response);
}
```

---

**Problem:**

As said before, the application is halting immediately after a button is pressed! Briefly this is what happens after btnMicorTimer_Click :( It's look like the project is trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: What do you mean by halting? You did add a Sleep on the UI thread...

Comment: I've desired this: http://postimage.org/image/f0lnt11bp/ But site rules doesn't let me add this photo in my post! BTW: 
Application give huge resources and not responding ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The peak you see can easily be explained:

You are requesting a UI update every millisecond by adding an item to the listbox.

That will slow down the response of the UI considerably.

Comment: Tanx Erno, but what was caused wonder to me wasn't PEAK in UI (as I foresight for it): What's unacceptable to me is: Why must application not responding! delay doesn't matter.
I forced each time (even with 100ms of MicroTimer working) to End task application to back to normal...

Comment: It is not responding because you are spamming the UI thread with messages. It is simply too busy to respond to user actions. (I don't understand the last line of your comment)

Comment: Thanks for your time, I mean: when my spamming the UI thread finished, basically it must respond normally! Isn't it true?

Comment: No, it will respond normally AFTER all the messages have been processed. In a situation like this it might be better to add the messages to a list and update the UI with this list every second or so. That will free the UI thread. Who can read 1000 messages in one second anyway?

Comment: OK, I try this before and it's work with List<string>: but my point is about this case (without generic list, ...) => even by changing System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); {for 100 messages!} application would not respond after 1 hour!